# How do you use CakePHP Auth component across subdomains?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

(Using CakePHP) I'm looking to setup a sub-domain for user creation, password changes and credit card information vies...as in:

secure.mydomain.com (https)
- User/Create
- User/Login 
- User/UpdateCreditCardInfo

app.mydomain.com (http)
- once logged in using the "secure" site, the user will be able to access application specific views

Using the CakePHP Auth component on both my sub-domains...how do I persist the login information when the user is authenticated on "secure" then is redirected to "app" sub-domain?

Answer (score 3):

See: http://book.cakephp.org/view/173/Sessions

To provide a custom configuration, set Session.save Configuration to a filename. CakePHP will use your file in the CONFIGS directory for the settings.

```
Configure::write('Session.save','my_session');
```

This will allow you to customize session handling.

```
// Cookie path is now '/' even if you app is within a sub 
// directory on the domain
$this->path = '/';
ini_set('session.cookie_path', $this->path);

// Session cookie now persists across all subdomains
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', env('HTTP_BASE'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a general problem with cookies. They're only valid within the domain they were set and its subdomains. `app.example.com` is not a subdomain of `secure.example.com`, so you can't transition cookies between them.

You *can* set a cookie at `example.com` and make it valid for all its subdomains, including `app.` and `secure.`. You can then modify the cookie on these subdomains.